# Set certain desktop environment as default, and revert back to it after reboot

Tags: linux-mint, desktop-environment, lightdm, display-manager

first of all, let me put a few things out of the way: I'm about to manage a few (semi-)public workstations with Linux Mint 20 that a lot of different people have access to. And you know people; they leave their stuff on the desktop and change a setting here and there, etc.

That's why I want the system to reset everything after each reboot. I already done the major part (running a script at every boot that restores the home folder), but one thing doesn't reset via this kinda sledgehammer approach - the desktop environment. The workstations have both Cinnamon (which should always be the default when "freshly" booted) and KDE installed.

In short: If a user prefers to work with KDE they are free to do so (otherwise it wouldn't be installed in the first place). But after a reboot I'd like the display manager (which is LightDM, I assume) to preselect Cinnamon - or, if auto-login is enabled, to boot right into Cinnamon, instead of the recently used Plasma desktop.

Obviously, I already googled this and yes, there are some other questions that go in the same direction, but I've yet to find a solution that works. One common answer is editing the `.dmrc` file (which doesn't already exist on my installation) in the home directory, but that seems to deprecated or ignored.

Can anyone help me with a per-user default DE setting?

Comment: Can you confirm your display manager?  `lightdm`, `gdm`, `sddm` or `lxdm` are common ones.  If someone installs a desktop environment, it will often bring in a display manager, leaving several installed (but one running).  I suspect the answer will be display-manager-specific.

Comment: This might be a good play to look for lightdm: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM#Changing_the_Default_Session

Comment: I agree with Steward, check which DM is used: `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager` or `systemctl status display-manager`.

Comment: Edit question to tell us: Is resetting after a logout acceptable? Should there be persistence of may files? Can a user save files?